# Inappropriate exception when apache camel interceptor throws one

Tags: java, apache-camel, interceptor, spring-camel

I created an interceptor to test the exception handler in Camel route.
Here's an interceptor:

```java
context.getRouteDefinition("AnalisingResponse").adviceWith(context,
            new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage")
                        .routeId("interceptor")
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .throwException(exception);
                }
            });
```

route i wish to apply adviceWith:

```java
      from("direct:AnalisingResponse")
            .routeId("AnalisingResponse")
            .log("start PsASetStatementProcessor_AnalisingResponse")
            .process(exchange -> {
                exchange.setProperty(CONDITION,
                    bodyDataContainer(exchange)
                        .getValue("/*[1]/Body/container/Msg/BSMessage/BSError/@Cod")  // TODO local-name
                );
            })
            .process((BaseAction) exchange -> {
                DataContainer localBody = propertyDataContainer(exchange, LOCAL_BODY);

                Long serviceId = Long.parseLong(localBody.getValue("/Message/ServiceID"));
                Long taskId = Long.parseLong(localBody.getValue("/Message/TaskID"));
                Long statusId = 39L;
                Long mtType = 0L;

                String requestVar = bsDbSwiftCorpService.updateTask(taskId, serviceId, mtType, statusId);

                exchange.setProperty(REQUEST_VAR, requestVar);
            })
            .process((BaseAction) exchange -> {
                DataContainer localBody = propertyDataContainer(exchange, LOCAL_BODY);
                localBody.replace("./Message/MessageStatusID", "3");
                exchange.setProperty(LOCAL_BODY, localBody);

                template.sendBody(PsMessageLogger.DIRECT_ROUTE_UPDATE_MESSAGE, localBody.copy());
            });
```

and here's a route, i wish to intercept:

```java
        from("direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage")
                .routeId("PsMessageLogger_updateMessage")
                .log("start PsMessageLogger_updateMessage")
                .onException(Exception.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .to("direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage_errorHandler")
                .end()
                .process((BaseAction) exchange -> {
                    DataContainer body = bodyDataContainer(exchange);

                    Long messageID = new Long(body.getValue("/Message/MessageID"));
                    Long messageStatusID = new Long(body.getValue("/Message/MessageStatusID"));
                    Long taskID = new Long(body.getValue("/Message/TaskID"));
                    Long taskStatusGenID = new Long(body.getValue("/Message/TaskStatusGenID"));

                    bsMessageLoggerToDbService.updateMessage(messageID, messageStatusID, taskID, taskStatusGenID);
                });
```

But as a result, the EXCEPTION_CAUGHT property contains not the exception thrown by me, but `org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException` where cause is a NullPointerException. Here's its stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-SERVO-1598117736905-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1842)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:715)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168)
    at ru.vtb.swiftcorp.psASetStatementProcessor.proxy.services.PsASetStatementProcessor.lambda$configure$8(PsASetStatementProcessor.java:149)
    at ru.vtb.swiftcorp.common.BaseAction.process(BaseAction.java:30)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:529)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:494)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:494)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:229)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.send(DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.java:306)
    at ru.vtb.swiftcorp.psASetStatementProcessor.proxy.services.PsASetStatementProcessorTest.testSuccessRoute_caseExceptionOnPsMessageLogger_updateMessage(PsASetStatementProcessorTest.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.addFirst(ArrayDeque.java:233)
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.push(ArrayDeque.java:508)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.FatalFallbackErrorHandler.process(FatalFallbackErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.deliverToFailureProcessor(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1063)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:474)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.InterceptSendToEndpointProcessor.process(InterceptSendToEndpointProcessor.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:529)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:494)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:494)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:229)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161)
    ... 66 more
```

Everything that was possible to understand that the error occurs in the method `public boolean process(final Exchange exchange, final AsyncCallback callback)` of `org.apache.camel.processor.FatalFallbackErrorHandler` when trying to put null value in the deque.

How do i get the exception i need in the error handler?

Comment: Can you add the route you are trying to test?

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak i added it

Comment: None of the routes you added have a routeId of `AnalisingResponse` which is what you have mentioned in your interceptor. Also I couldn't see any route sending to `direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage`

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak i updated routes, added ``routeId``, but the problem still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage")` looks for the actual string `direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage` when attempting to intercept. In your `AnalisingResponse` route, you are doing it dynamically in your processor which is why it is unable to intercept.

In the 3rd processor in your `AnalisingResponse`, remove the Producer Template and set the `localBody` as your message body like so: `exchange.getIn().setBody(localBody)`. Then after the process method, add a `to("direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage")`.

Your `AnalisingResponse` route should look like this:

```
from("direct:AnalisingResponse")
    .routeId("AnalisingResponse")
    .log("start PsASetStatementProcessor_AnalisingResponse")
    .process(exchange -> {
        //...
    })
    .process((BaseAction) exchange -> {
        //...
    })
    .process((BaseAction) exchange -> {
        DataContainer localBody = propertyDataContainer(exchange, LOCAL_BODY);
        localBody.replace("./Message/MessageStatusID", "3");
        exchange.setProperty(LOCAL_BODY, localBody);
        
        exchange.getIn().setBody(localBody);
    })
    .to("direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is works. But it looks a little strange, because my interceptor works, when i send body throught ``ProducerTemplate.sendBody()`` method, and at first throws exceptions i expect, but later another one exception happens inside ``FatalFallbackErrorHandler``.

Comment: The producertemplate sends the localBody successfully. But your `interceptSendToEndpoint` cannot find the `direct:PsMessageLogger_updateMessage`

Comment: Then I cannot understand why such  a other successfull test case passes successfully: ``messageLoggerMock.message(0).body().isEqualTo(localBody);`` . In this case message logger interceptor redirect exchange to messageLoggerMock.

Comment: Is there a repository you can share so I can have a look?